# B-Tree, difficulties to understand

Tags: algorithm, b-tree

I need to find out what would be the keys contained in the final level of data-bearing nodes if I insert value in increasing order in it. My BTree is of order 3, and I would like to know how to plot it, if insert values from 0 to 15.
Thanks in advance for help,
eo

Comment: Why don't you start inserting them with a pen and paper, and see how it goes? for 15 elements it won't be too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B-Tree with max key size of 3. The order depends of definition,  "Bayer & McCreight 1972" or  "Knuth 1998".

```
└── 3, 7, 11
    ├── 0, 1, 2
    ├── 4, 5, 6
    ├── 8, 9, 10
    └── 12, 13, 14
```

[B-Tree Java source](http://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/BTree.java)